# Getting Error Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded in Google Sheets for URL Shortener API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting "Error Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup" in google sheets with using URL Shortener API (image as below)

[image: Error Image]

Below is my code in Script Editor

```
function shortenURL(urlField) {
  var toShorten = UrlShortener.newUrl().setLongUrl(urlField);
  var shortened = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten);
  return shortened.getId();
}
```

I have bonded to the API through Google Sheets build-in setting from "Cloud Platform Project", enabled URL Shortener API in "Advanced Google Services", enabled it in Google API Console, and created both API and OAuth (image as below). Besides, I was just using it for less than 20 cells in the Google Sheets, and so I am sure it is way less than the quote given by Google.

Cloud Platform Project
[image: Cloud Platform Project]

Advanced Google Services
[image: Advanced Google Services]

Enable in Google API Console
[image: Enable in Google API Console]

[image]

If I use the below code (mentioned [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76050/google-sheets-function-to-get-a-shortened-url-from-bit-ly-or-goo-gl-etc)), it works fine.
However, I want the script to run automatically as the function instead of by clicking the button. Therefore, I still want to solve the error.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Shorten")
    .addItem("Go !!","rangeShort")
    .addToUi()  
}

function rangeShort() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
    output.push([url.id]);
  }
  range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);
}
```

I found some post mentioned the solution to this error is to apply authentication to the requests to Google. However, I have already created API key and OAuth and bond them to Google Sheets through those Google Sheets build-in setting.

Is there any solution to the error?
If the error occurs due to authentication issue, how I can apply the authentication in addition to those setting I have already done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending a POST request to UrlShortener API endpoint instead of using the UrlShortener service in Apps Script. With UrlShortener.Url.insert(), I quickly hit the usage quota.

Append the API url with the 'key' parameter and set it equal to the API key you obtained from Developer console.

In the body of your POST request, set 'muteHttpExceptions' to 'true' to log all error messages as beautified JSON.

```
var API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";

function shortenUrl(longUrl) {

  var apiEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=" + API_KEY;

  var data = {  
    "longUrl": longUrl  
  }

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiEndpoint, options).getContentText();

  var data = JSON.parse(response);     
  return data.id;

}
```

Comment: Your solution work!!
Whole flow that I set up URL Shortener with your solution is as below:

1. Create new Google Sheets with fields I needed; e.g. Cell A2 with Original URL, and Cell B2 with the desired result - Shortened URL
2. Use formula "=IF(LEN(A2),shortenURL(A2),"")" in Cell B2
3. Go to script editor
4. Use code provided by Anton
5. Enable URL Shortener in Advanced Google Service
6. Enable URL Shortener API in Google API Console
7. Create API Key and use the paste the key in code provided by Anton
8. Grant permission to the project in Google Sheets
9. Here you go!!